# Cannot show name or null from api when after login using getParcelableExtra

Tags: kotlin, retrofit, parcelable, mobile-development

I want to display the name, what happens is that the name cannot be displayed or null. Here I use `getParcelableExtra`, I think my code still has errors, but I don't understand where the error is.

this is the function that will display the name

```
private fun receiveData() {
        val user = activity?.intent?.getParcelableExtra<LoginNewResponse>("EXTRA_NAME")
        binding.tvName.text = user?.result?.name
    }
```

this is a variable in the LoginActivity.kt

```
val intent = Intent(this, DashboardActivity::class.java).also {
                                it.putExtra("EXTRA_NAME", data.result.name)
                                startActivity(it)
                            }
```

and the last, this is the LoginResponse

```
@Parcelize
data class LoginNewResponse(

    @field:SerializedName("result")
    val result: LoginResult,

    @field:SerializedName("error")
    val error: Boolean,

    @field:SerializedName("message")
    val message: String
) : Parcelable

@Entity(tableName = "login")
@Parcelize
data class LoginResult(

    @field:SerializedName("role")
    val role: String,

    @field:SerializedName("name")
    val name: String,

    @field:SerializedName("userId")
    val userId: String,

    @field:SerializedName("email")
    val email: String,

    @field:SerializedName("token")
    val token: String
) : Parcelable
```

I don't know where the error is

Thankyou for the answer